# Count Integer Words from Sentences

Tags: java

I have a Sentence which contains like "**Count 225989 the 20124 integer 20124 122 words"**

I want to Count the total number of Integer Words from it.
Like Above string contains 4 integer words of 225989 , 20124 , 20124 , 122.
Please help me with this..

I just tried split the words

```
String str ="Sentences";
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
```

Comment: Please post some code you've already tried.

Comment: i just tried split the words
String str ="Sentences";
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));

Comment: Now loop through the `split` and search on google about How to check whether a `String` is a Digit or Not

Comment: Then try to parse the each *word* you split as integers and count it. Another advanced approach is using regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using ascii code to detect if character is a number.

```
// main program
String str = "Count 225989 the 20124 integer 20124 122 words"
String[] splitted = str.split(" ");
for (String s : splitted){
    if(isNumber(s))
         System.out.println(s);
}

public boolean isNumber(String s){
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
        if(c<48 || c>57){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
package com.vr1.challenges;
```

public class IntegerSplit {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Count 225a989 the 20124 integer 20124 122 words";
    int count=0;
            String[] splitted = str.split(" ");
            for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++)
            {
                //System.out.println(splitted[i]); 
                boolean containsalpha=false;

                if(splitted[i].matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*"))
                {

                    //System.out.println("contains alpha "+splitted[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("does not contains alpha "+splitted[i]);
                }
                //System.out.println("\n****\n");
            }


}
```

}